# Select the record ids in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a table and i need to pull all the ids (all the primary keys) corresponding a certain pattern. I need this to be done with the model class in Yii and save them to an array for further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do what it seems like you are asking. In this example the model is "People" and the pattern is `job_title LIKE "%developer%"` -- post-processing is done to put into an array. If you can use an object, skip the post processing.

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 'people_id';
$criteria->condition='job_title LIKE :txt';
$criteria->params=array(':txt'=>'%developer%');
$people=People::model()->findAll($criteria);
// save to array:
$people_a = array();
foreach ($people as $person) {
    $people_a[] = $person['people_id'];
}
```

A slightly more efficient way to do it (if you need the result to be an array) that allows you to use CommandBuilder and your existing models is:

```
$model = People::model();
$model->dbCriteria->condition .= 'job_title LIKE :txt';
$model->dbCriteria->select = 'people_id';
$model->dbCriteria->params = array(':txt'=>'%developer%');

$people = $model->getCommandBuilder()
    ->createFindCommand($model->tableSchema, $model->dbCriteria)
    ->queryAll();

$people_a = array();
array_walk($people, function ($value) use (& $people_a) {
    $people_a[] = $value['people_id'];
});
```

(the anonymous function above assumes PHP 5.3)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to select only IDs with ActiveRecord pattern. You can use CCommandBuilder to build sql query.